# How can the Phabricator "maniphest.edit" API be used to add a ticket to a column while also using its "beforePHIDs" parameter?

Tags: phabricator, maniphest

According to the maniphest.edit "Transaction Type: Column" [documentation](https://phab.wmflabs.org/conduit/method/maniphest.edit/), the `beforePHIDs` parameter should be an array of PHIDs. I *think* this would look like the following:

```
curl https://5555/api/maniphest.edit \
    -d api.token=api-token \
    -d transactions[0][type]=column \
    -d transactions[0][value][0][columnPHID]=PHID-PCOL-6666 \
    -d transactions[0][value][0][beforePHIDs][0]=PHID-TASK-7777 \
    -d objectIdentifier=PHID-TASK-8888
```

However, when invoked as such (with `beforePHIDs` as an array) I get the following error, which seems to contradict the documentation:

`Exception when processing transaction of type "column": Error while reading "value[0]": Expected string, got something else.`

How does my curl statement need to change for this to work? I've tried every permutation I can think of. Or is this perhaps a bug?

Side note - this works fine, but it doesn't allow control for the ticket insertion point:

```
curl https://5555/api/maniphest.edit \
    -d api.token=api-token \
    -d transactions[0][type]=column \
    -d transactions[0][value][0]=PHID-PCOL-6666 \
    -d objectIdentifier=PHID-TASK-8888
```